# Why do stuffed shells recipes include eggs?

Tags: eggs, cheese, pasta, italian-cuisine

I'm making stuffed shells, but I don't have any eggs. All the recipes I can find call for one or two eggs. What is the reason and can I get away without eggs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eggs are for binding - they keep the filling together. They might also provide some substance/body to the filling. Not knowing what recipes you're looking at, it's hard to say for sure, but since you tagged this with "cheese" I'm guessing that the fillings would start to melt and ooze out of the shells if you didn't use egg.

Comment: I'm using ricotta cheese, I decided to add some milk to make it more spreadable. Cooking now, will see how it works.

Comment: Er... spreadable? In terms of holding together, you've made it worse. You now have more liquid.

Comment: Just finished eating, everything came out ok. I used three cheeses in the stuffing: ricotta, mozzarella, and parmesan. Taste was great but noticed slightly different texture from what I'm used to.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say if you're not going to use eggs, add breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 4):

Mashed potato or potato flakes will act as a binder. Use about 2 tablespoons per egg. You may need to adjust. (I have a mother-in-law with egg allergies.)

Answer (score -1):

Though this is a bit delayed, I actually didn't have eggs today and am using spinach, ground beef, ricotta, mozzarella, parm. No eggs necessary.

Comment: Did you notice any flavor or consistency differences from when you make the same recipe with eggs?